# Dynamically Button in Android studio

Tags: android

[image]

I'm trying to create an Add button that can dynamically create a button, but I have a problem in the following:

`Button mybutton = new Button (this);`

I have no idea why `this` can be applied in `OnClickListener`.

Comment: **this** in this case mean ***context*** ```Button mybutton = new Button (Context);```

Comment: @DanhDC no it doesn't

Comment: I mean, you must be change **this** to your **context** like this ```Button mybutton = new Button (Context);```

Comment: No not like that, that's just the constructor signature. It can take any context

Comment: replace `this` with `YourActivity.this`

Answer (score 5):

You are inside `View.OnClickListener` so using `this` you are passing `OnClickListener` instead of context, which is illegal.

Use `HalamanDepanActivity.this`

Answer (score 1):

This is the constructor of `Button` in Android

```
 public Button (Context context)
```

in your case, `this` is not a `Context`
so you need to change `this` to `getApplicationContext()` or HalamanDepanActivity.this

Answer (score 1):

The [Documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/thiskey.html) says:

> Within an instance method or a constructor, this is a reference to the
>   current object — the object whose method or constructor is being
>   called. You can refer to any member of the current object from within
>   an instance method or a constructor by using this.

You are use `this` keyword inner side of **onClick** so it will take reference of current Method.

You have to pass `YourActivity.this` instead `this`

or

You can try with `Context` like:

```
Context context = getApplicationContext();
Button button = new Button(context);
```

May it will clear concept about `this`

Thank you.

Comment: I would avoid using `getApplicationContext()` for views. Just use `getActivity()` or `v.getContext()` instead;

Comment: if answer is helpful to you should accept :) @JoshParinussa